# Is it possible to add support of a custom RTOS's threads to GDB?

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, rtos

In the scenario of debugging a remote target running a custom RTOS, what would be necessary to add thread support to GDB?

In my case I have access to the RTOS sources and debug info for all its scheduler's symbols, so theoretically the information is accessible.

Would this imply recompiling GDB? Adding hooks to thread-related commands?

Any commentary will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you type `info threads` in GDB, what information do you get back?  What requests does it make to your target?  You should be able to use that information to get it working.

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have mentioned I had already tried that. GDB answers with a "this target does not support threads" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add thread support (and in particular, support for `H` and `qXfer:threads:read` packets) for your gdb RTOS stub. Documentation [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Packets.html#Packets) and [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/General-Query-Packets.html#qXfer%20threads%20read).

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't thought to look into the packets documentation. Your links will be a great start.

Comment: As stated in http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/ELC-E%20Linux%20Awareness.pdf the JTAG solution for RTOS awareness is preferable to modifications in the RTOS itself. But I do not think that GDB C extensions are the way to go, because there could not be a dependency for every RTOS in GDB. Therefore I would prefer the python extension way. But it seems, that the thread handling is not exposed to python yet. Does anyone have more information? Is it planned?

Comment: Found newer slides and something from the mailing list:
http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/Debugging%20the%20Linux%20Kernel%20with%20GDB.pdf
https://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2015-06/msg00040.html